# JS Outbound Video Call with Twilio WebRTC Go

Tags: javascript, twilio, webrtc, video-streaming, twilio-api

Is it possible to make 1:1 outbound video calls with Twilio?
If yes can anyone showcase a simple js example doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio Video WebRTC Go can connect two users in a video room. Twilio Video does not provide any specific tools for making an outbound video call in JavaScript though, so you will need to build a notification system yourself to handle that. I do not have an example for this.

If you have a specific issue when implementing this, I recommend you open a new question and share some code so the community can see what you've tried and help out.

Comment: Thank philnash. I will try to use notifications to create a outbound call experience following https://www.twilio.com/docs/notify/quickstart/firebase-web